# Parsed JSON contains only the last element

Tags: javascript, json

In the following code after converting the JSON string to object the second console statement gives me only the last element the first element is ignored. Why? How can I get the first element?

```
        var key_val_pair = keyvalues;  
        console.log(key_val_pair);  //{"4":"123","4":"456"}

        key_val_pair = JSON.parse(key_val_pair);
        console.log(key_val_pair); // {"4":"456"}
       for(var entry in key_val_pair)
       {
            console.log(entry); 
            console.log(key_val_pair[entry]); 
       }
```

Comment: Your JSON gives two values for the key "4", which is meaningless. What did you expect? If you want multiple values for the same key you have to use an array: `{"4":["123", "456"]}`.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Are you saying, you are not able to guess why the first element is missing? ;)

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the terminology a bit.

Comment: @Juhana Good one. This title makes more sense :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each key within an object is unique. So when you convert your object (with the duplicate key `4`) to an object, one of the values has to be dropped.

*Note:* You do not convert the string to JSON. The string contains JSON and you convert it to a JavaScript object!

Answer (score 1):

What would you expect if you had

```
var a;
a = "123";
a = "456";
```

Would you expect to have both 123 and 456? No, you expect to have just 456 since it overrides the original value of 123. Same thing happens in your object, the second "4" key overrides the first value.

If you need to have multiple values per key, than it needs to be an Array. What it should look like is

```
{ "4": ["123","456"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = 1;
console.log(myArray[0]);
myArray[0] = 2;
console.log(myArray[0]);
```

What would you expect the second `console.log` to print? Obviously, `2`, right? Because, we write to the same index.

The same way, in the JSON data, `456` is written to the same location where `123` was stored earlier. That is why, first element is missing.